# How can I with formcheck ? regex: date

Tags: regex, mootools

How can I do to check a date in format dd/mm/yyyy with formcheck ?

Answer (score 0):

`(\d){2}/(\d){2}/(\d){4}` works to simple check that there are 2 day digits etc.

However, for a more comprehensive check that it is actually a valid date, use:

```
((([012](\d))|(3)[01])/((0[1-9])|((1)[012]))/((\d){4}))
```

Comment: A little overboard on the parentheses. `([012]\d|3[01])/(0[1-9]|1[012])/\d{4}`

Comment: Probably but I like to be sure what the `|` is actually using. I had a regex implemented without proper group identification and took me several hours to find it. Been thorough ever since.